# What are Scala annotations actually?

Tags: scala, annotations

I don't know Java, and I started learning Scala. What are annotations and what are they for?

Answer (score 8):

Annotations are meta-data attached to classes/methods/fields and can be used by frameworks to determine required functionality surrounding those classes/methods/fields.

Common uses include:

1. marking methods as unit-test methods and for associated set-up/tear-down (e.g. JUnit and TestNG)
2. marking classes and fields for persistence (e.g. Hibernate)
3. marking classes and fields to be exposed as JMX beans

Annotations are a Java feature, and as such available in Scala as well as Java.

Comment: Annotations are a Java feature with support in the JVM, to be sure, but that doesn't make them automatically a part of Scala.

Comment: In particular, since you can annotate things in Scala that you cannot annotate in Java, or that don't even *exist* in Java, I'm pretty sure that Scala Annotations are not just a simple 1:1 mapping to either Java Annotations or JVM Annotations.

Comment: I'm not making assertions that there's a one-to-one mapping. But I *am* saying that Java annotations are supported in the JVM and available in Scala. All the above fit into that category.

Answer (score 5):

Annotations, in general, make it possible to associate information with a definition e.g. the definition of a class, method or variable. Annotations can be used by the compiler or accessed by other parts of your program e.g. in Java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
void useADeprecatedMethod() {
    someObj.someDeprecatedMethod();
}
```

Here, the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation tells the compiler not to issue a warning about `useADeprecatedMethod's` use of `someDeprecatedMethod`.

Other uses in the Java world include adding information to a class regarding how it maps to a relational database for use by OR mappers like Hibernate.

In Scala, a number of things which are keywords or marker interfaces in Java are implemented as annotations in Scala. e.g. `@throws`, `@serializable`.

Here is an example showing Scala and Java working together with the help on an annotation. Imagine we're going to define a `Person` class in Scala. When we come to use `Person` in Java, the Java programmer will expect us to have `setName` and `getName` methods as is the bean convention in Java. This can be achieved using the `@BeanProperty` annotation:

Person class in Scala:

```
class Person {
  @BeanProperty
  var name = "Joe Bloggs"
}
```

In Java:

```
public void printPerson(Person p) {
    // Scala added the getName method for us
    System.out.println(p.getName());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

One interesting aspect of Java annotations is control over their *retention*. When an annotation type (a Java class that implements the `Annotation` interface) is defined, one of its properties is its `RetentionPolicy`, one of:

- SOURCE — Annotations are to be discarded by the compiler.
- CLASS — Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler but need not be retained by the VM at run time.
- RUNTIME — Annotations are to be recorded in the class file by the compiler and retained by the VM at run time, so they may be read reflectively.